# update query not working in symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

i am trying to update my form but i got the error, my code is

```
$qs= Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->update('login l')
                ->set('l.username', $name)
                ->set('l.message', $message)
                ->set('l.email', $email)
                ->set('l.subject', $sub)
                ->set('l.doc', $path)
                ->where('l.id=?',$id)
                ->execute();
                $this->redirect('user/show?id=' . $id);
```

Comment: And the error is... ??

Comment: error is 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception

Comment: The point comes just after you cut off... What's the exception?

Comment: 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':\xampp\htdocs\login\web\uploads/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709_56ceeb' at line 1

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting a new (duplicate) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print out the SQL statement:

```
$qs= Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->update('login l')
                ->set('l.username', $name)
                ->set('l.message', $message)
                ->set('l.email', $email)
                ->set('l.subject', $sub)
                ->set('l.doc', $path)
                ->where('l.id=?',$id);
echo $qs->getSQL();
```

Check the statement for syntax error.

Comment: got the same error :(

Comment: It seems there's a syntax error in the SQL. Can you get the SQL statement? Like `$qs = Doctrine_Query::create()->update(...)->set(..); var_dump($qs->getSql());`

Comment: i got this kind of error.                                                                 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':\xampp\htdocs\login\web\uploads/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709_56cee‌​b' at line 1

Comment: In such cases, the best practice is to take the full SQL query Doctrine would try to execute and look at. If it's not obvious what the error is, paste it into a MySQL command line console and execute it in order to find the error.

Comment: but i dont know how it done

Comment: okay done it. just single qoute cannot passed during sql query